# Accessing a mapping variable from web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-debugging, mapping, abi

Is there a way to access a mapping variable such as:

```
mapping(bytes => bool) myMappingVar;
```

which is **NOT:**

- Declared **public** explicitly
- without using **indexed** based id
- Also no corresponding public getter method is set

For example, from web3:

```
contract.instance.methods.myMappingVar('somevalue').call();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not conveniently, but you can access any value in a smart contract's storage via `web3.eth.getStorageAt`. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage for the details of how storage is laid out.

If your `mapping` is the first state variable in the contract, so it's at slot 0, this code will retrieve the value for the key `0x123456`.

```
var slot = "0".repeat(64);  // hex uint256 representation of 0
var key = "0x123456";  // hex representation of the key

web3.eth.getStorageAt(
  contractAddress,  // address of the contract to read from
  web3.sha3(key+slot, { encoding: 'hex' }),  // keccak256(k . p)
  function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);  // 00...0 for false, 00...1 for true, both 32 bytes wide
  }
);
```

Comment: What is the slot? Is it an index of the mapping variable?

Comment: "Slot" is the name given to the position in storage where some value resides.

Comment: I dont understand. How do I get a slot for a mapping with key 'height' such as:
```
['age': true, 'name': true, 'height': true]
```

also see, my question states without using or assuming indexes to be a known value

Comment: Just use `key = web3.fromAscii('height')` in the above code.

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks. But what should be the value for slot? 0?

Comment: It depends on where the `mapping` is in your Solidity code. If it's the first variable, then the slot will be 0. If not, you'll really have to read the documentation I linked to for the details.

Comment: Ok got it. I was in the assumption that, slot is referring to an index for the mapping variable

Answer (score 9):

You can access a public mapping variable like a regular public variable with the exception that you need to **provide the index value for the mapping**.

I have done the following example, and it worked for me

In my contract written using Solidity

```
address public owner; 
mapping(uint8 => address) public incomingQueue;
mapping(address => string) public assignedName;
```

After I obtain the contract address:

```
const contract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(contract_address);
```

I can access these variable using the following web3 javascript code:

```
contract.owner.call(function(err, result){
     if(!err)
         alert(result)
 });
contract.incomingQueue.call(0, function(err, result){
     if(!err){
        alert(result)
     }
 });
contract.assignedName.call(web3.eth.accounts[0], function(err, result){
     if(!err){
        alert(result)
     }
 });
```

Comment: Using this method i am getting the error Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: This is for older versions of web3. On web3 version 1.2 you should call it as contract.methods.incomingQueue(0).call();

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of information hiding, you can not access fields from outside. You need a getter function. When you specify the public modifier on the mapping, Solidity generates a getter function for you.

However, as smarx is explaining in his answer, this is not protecting your data from being read directly from the storage.

Comment: From outside the EVM, you can read anything stored in a smart contract.

Comment: Oh.. you're assuming the question is asked from the perspective of securing the data? Then of course "You can not access fields from outside" is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what the perspective is... the question just says "is there a way."

Comment: Upvoting your answer as soon as I recovered from "Vox Populi". ;-)

Comment: @smarx's answer is more inclined towards a possible answer.